# Python Search a Set using case-insensitive

Tags: python, search, set, case-insensitive

I have 3 sets and a dict. My sets look something like this:

```
set1 = set(['Bob', 'Jim', 'RALPH'])
set2 = set(['Jill', 'Nadeen', 'WaterBottle'])
set3 = set(['ThisIsOne', 'ThisIsTwo'])
all_names = {'first_one': set1, 
             'second_one': set2, 
             'third_one': set3, 
             'all':set1 | set2 | set3}

#I can make it work if I do this:
r = re.search(input, "','".join(all_names['all'])
if r:
    name = all_names[r.group()]
```

My user will pass in either one of the names in the first three sets, or one of the keys in all_names. The names the user passes in will not be case sensitive, but I need to return the corresponding names as they are capitalized in the set(s). I have no problem getting the list of names if they pass in a key, but is there a good way that if the user passes in say 'nadeen', I can find it easily (and efficiently) in all_names['all']?

But, my boss doesn't think this is the best approach. Is there a way to use comprehension for this? Any other ideas?

Comment: How many sets are there in your real code? Also, what objections does your boss have against this approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, rather naive approach would be to iterate over `all_names['all']` and make a case-insensitive check, like this:

```
input = input.lower()
result = [item for item in all_names['all'] if item.lower() == input]
```

Or, another way is to search in the list that contains lower-cased items from the set:

```
input.lower() in map(lambda x: x.lower(), all_names['all'])
```

Comment: The second approach doesn't work on python3.x.  You could do something like `ilower = input.lower(); any(x.lower() == ilower for x in all_names['all'])` which gets you short circuiting.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have mentioned that I am using 2.7, but good to know about 3.0 for the future

Answer (score 0):

I would create a dictionary mapping lowercase words to words with proper capitalization:

```
>>> set1 = set(['Bob', 'Jim', 'RALPH'])
>>> set2 = set(['Jill', 'Nadeen', 'WaterBottle'])
>>> set3 = set(['ThisIsOne', 'ThisIsTwo'])
>>> d = {x.lower():x for x in set1|set2|set3}
>>> d
{'thisistwo': 'ThisIsTwo', 'thisisone': 'ThisIsOne', 'waterbottle': 'WaterBottle', 'jim': 'Jim', 'ralph': 'RALPH', 'jill': 'Jill', 'nadeen': 'Nadeen', 'bob': 'Bob'}
```

Now you just need to validate the lowercase input.  From your post, it's hard to say whether you should use a dictionary for each set, or just on master dictionary, but I think the ultimate idea is the same.